# EmailMessage or EmailMessageRelation parent record

Tags: enhanced-emails

We are using enhanced emails and activity capture.
I want to find the date of first email sent to a Lead or Contact.

When I try to query this I see that the **EmailMessage** and **EmailMessageRelation** records do not have a PartnerId/RelationId/ActivityId, except for when they are connected to a Case.

It seems there is not database connection between the email and the Lead/Contact.
What am I missing? How can I the first email sent to the Lead/Contact?

Comment: It depends on how you had sent those emails. You can send an email to a lead email without actually link the email message to the lead record. Can you better explain how these messages are sent?

Comment: @ gvgramazio emails are sent from outlook and are created in salesforce via the activity capture